# Change int to match column number on columnheader.MouseDoubleClick

Tags: search, datagridview

The question is fairly self explanatory but here goes anyway:

User double clicks the column he'd like to search , int = column number , search `table[row_iterator][int] return all matches`. (I'd like the user to choose because it's not always going to be the same column/file)

Also, I'm working on a pretty big file, 200k records + 50k (monthly), in an Excel file. Any suggestions on searching this without killing the PC it's running on for 3 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that I understand your question since you basically answer it yourself in the question title.

The DataGridView provides several events that handle double click, including as you mention, `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick`.

The two events I've would look at are: `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick` and `CellDoubleClick` where the difference between them is that with `ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick` you only get the event where the header row is double clicked, while `CellDoubleClick` is raised for the whole grid. (well, also, with the Mouse version you can capture more than just the left mouse button).

Below are handlers for each of these events, both of which have their own Args object, which can be used to retrieve the column index you are looking for.

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name);
}
```

The secondary question about searching through a large Excel file really deserves to be its own quesiton - you need to give a bit more information about the contents of that file and where it comes from to get the best answer.

Comment: Thanks man, it's the `e.ColumnIndex` I was looking for. _slinks away feeling like a noob_

Comment: @Dani don't feel bad about it - particularly because several of the Argument objects for DGV events don't provide the columnIndex property and you do need to use other tricks to work out where in the grid you are.